# What is behind command line tools that can continously update the same line?

Tags: backgroundworker, stdout

I use RTMPDump to download a mediastream and I want to redirect the output to a stream I can control so I can parse the progress and do something with that. But the program, like a lot of command line tools, has the progress shown in the same line that is then continously updated while the program is running. It will look something like this?

```
44929.160 kB / 556.34 sec
```

My questions are: Is this some kind of special character that deletes a character or line that makes the program able to rewrite the same line? Or is something else going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to print a carriage return at the beginning of each line:

```
# Using bash as an example
for i in {0..10}; do
  printf "\r%s" $i
  sleep 1
done
```

More complex formatting is possible using ANSI escape codes to position the cursor more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write the same line you have to delete the characters and overwrite them with the new ones. You can do that with giving the right amount of `backspaces` that delete the characters. 
The other option is to clear the complete console and rewrite it then. This can be done by `System("cls");` (C++ on Windows).